# Como ler json em angular1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic

Eu tenho o seguinte json

```
{"message": "457896","additionalData":{"google.message_id":"0:149534266","coldstart":false,"collapse_key":"com.ionicframework.lucasteste693113","foreground":true}}
```

Como posso dar um alert para mostrar todas as informações ?

Estou querendo mostrar todas as informações eu tentei fazer assim:

```
.controller('principalController', function($http, $scope, $sce, $stateParams, $ionicScrollDelegate, $timeout, $rootScope, $cordovaPushV5) {
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, notification){
        // esse nao veio 
        alert("result: " + JSON.stringify(notification.message) + JSON.stringify(notification.additionalData.google.message_id));
        //{"message": "457896","additionalData":{"google.message_id":"0:149534266","coldstart":false,"collapse_key":"com.ionicframework.lucasteste693113","foreground":true}}
    });
})
```

e mas não funciono alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade já está funcionando, o problema é esse campo google.message_id, pois ele tem um ponto no meio.
Faz assim:

```
.controller('principalController', function($http, $scope, $sce, $stateParams, $ionicScrollDelegate, $timeout, $rootScope, $cordovaPushV5) {
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, notification){
        _not= JSON.parse(notification);
        alert("result: " + _not.message + _not.additionalData["google.message_id"]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Eu tentei de novo com JSON.stringify e sem ele com esse igual voce coloco, sem as aspas mas nao funciono. Não apareceu nenhuma mensagem.

Comment: Fiz esse exemplo utilizando o próprio json que você postou:
https://jsfiddle.net/joserogerio84/L51kpnr8/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajudar Eu consegui fazer desse jeito :  alert("result: " + JSON.stringify(notification.message) + JSON.stringify(notification.additionalData["google.message_id"])); E funciono no alert.

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar todas as informações basta dar um 'stringify' no 'notification':

```
.controller('principalController', function($http, $scope, $sce, $stateParams, $ionicScrollDelegate, $timeout, $rootScope, $cordovaPushV5) {
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, notification){
        alert("notificação: " + JSON.stringify(notification));
    });
}
```

Editado:
Tenta dar um parse antes:

```
.controller('principalController', function($http, $scope, $sce, $stateParams, $ionicScrollDelegate, $timeout, $rootScope, $cordovaPushV5) {
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, notification){
        _not= JSON.parse(notification);
        alert("result: " + _not.message + _not.additionalData.google.message_id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Eu estou querendo mostrar todas as informações separadas colocar todos os valores separados exemplo : alert("result: " + JSON.stringify(notification.message) + JSON.stringify(notification.additionalData.google.message_id)); Mas quando eu coloco additionalData.google.message_id eu nao estou conseguindo pegar o valor que esta vindo do meu json

Comment: voce entendeu a minha duvida ? @joserogerio84

Comment: Entendi, o que sai quando você executa:
alert("notificação: " + JSON.stringify(notification));
??

Comment: notificação : {"message": "457896","additionalData":{"google.message_id":"0:149534266","coldstart":false,"collapse_key":"com.ionicframework.lucasteste693113","foreground":true}}

Comment: eu consegui pegar o message fazendo desse jeito : alert("notificação: " + JSON.stringify(notification.message)); Mas nao estou conseguindo pegar o resto.

Comment: Tenta dar um JSON.parse antes do alert.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: assim : JSON.parse(alert("result: " + JSON.stringify(notification.message) + JSON.stringify(notification.additionalData))); ???

Comment: Agora que eu acrescentei o parse que voce falo esta saindo desse jeito : notificação : {"message": "457896"{"google.message_id":"0:149534266"‌​,"coldstart":false,"‌​collapse_key":"com.i‌​onicframework.lucast‌​este693113","foregro‌​und":true}}

Comment: e agora como posso pegar essa informaçoes  que estao vindo pela {} ? @joserogerio84

Comment: Eu tentei fazer assim conforme vc edito na resposta :  _not= JSON.parse(notification);
        alert("result: " + JSON.stringify(_not.message) + JSON.stringify(_not.additionalData.google.message_id)); E eu tentei tambem sem o json.stringify Mas desse jeito o alert nao apareceu

Comment: Eu tentei fazer assim conforme vc edito na resposta :  _not= JSON.parse(notification);
        alert("result: " + JSON.stringify(_not.message) + JSON.stringify(_not.additionalData.google.message_id)); E eu tentei tambem sem o json.stringify Mas o alert nao apareceu nem com o json.stringify e nem sem ele.

Comment: Você teria mais alguma sugestão ? @joserogerio84